# best way to check availability of child page in confluence with parent page?

Tags: java, rest, api, confluence

I need to check availability of child page in parent page. I am able to achieve through this rest API

URL - https://ak.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/123457/child/page?limit=250

But it returns all available child page details, so i have to iterate through all results and check availability of one child page.
Problem --> 1. slower response due to response size, 2. Need to iterate through all result response.

I tried with this path - https://ak.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/search?cql=(parent=123457) , but this also doesn't help.

I am trying to find best way to check availability of child page. Could anyone suggest to best option to check availability of child page in parent page ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. 
Use URL - https://ak.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/search?cql=(title="test" and parent=parentID)